# Using facebook API breakdowns insights

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Trying to get the impressions per notification of specific group(by using ref).

By the api you can set a group for notifications by adding ref param to the notification request

That worked fine.

Now i am trying to use the API for getting **insights** as explained here:

[insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/app/app_insights?locale=en_GB#breakdowns)

I still dont understand how to pass the ref param.

this is my execution:

```
../app_insights/app_notification_impressions?breakdowns[0]=ref&access_token={acce‌​ss-token}
```

And in return I get this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "time": "2014-12-09T08:00:00+0000", 
      "value": "44", 
      "breakdowns": {
        "ref": "no_ref_specified"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How I am passing the request the ref value?

I tried all kind of combinations and I get errors.

I posted notification with diff ref. ref=test0099 and Now I see this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "time": "2014-12-09T08:00:00+0000", 
      "value": "3", 
      "breakdowns": {
        "ref": "no_ref_specified"
      }
    }, 
    {
      "time": "2014-12-10T08:00:00+0000", 
      "value": "1", 
      "breakdowns": {
        "ref": "test0099"
```

Maybe there is some bug over there?
thanks,
ray.

Comment: Have you tried putting the _actual_ value of your `ref` parameter in there, `breakdowns[0]=foo` (if your `ref` value was `foo`) …?

Comment: Yes I tried and I got this error:   "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Invalid Breakdown Name: 'foo'. Valid breakdowns for metric a2u_notif_imp are: age, acquisition_source,  publishing_actor_type"  .....
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue apparently to be a bug.
I have assigned this into facebook developers and now they taking care of it.

tracking at: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1512426199028095

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Stating your findings

> for some reason you cant notify with ref which is only numeric or start with numeric

Again, it still comes to down to file a bug.

---

From IRC, just stating that you should file a bug.

As long as the app is a canvas app and a game you should be able to see the desired response

```
HTTP POST /13608786/notifications with App Token and
template=Yo this is a test
ref=test0099
```

You should receive the notification

[image: Notif]

And be redirected to the canvas page

`https://apps.facebook.com/philippeharewood/?fb_source=notification&fb_ref=test0099&ref=notif&notif_t=app_notification`

The insights will reflect the same

HTTP GET /app/app_insights/app_notification_impressions?breakdowns[0]=ref

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "time": "2014-12-10T08:00:00+0000", 
      "value": "1", 
      "breakdowns": {
        "ref": "test0099"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the full http get insight request? where did you add the ref=test0099 param within the http request?

Comment: No. I mean How did you pass the ref input=test0099 into the insight request? what if you wanted to see insights of different ref-id?

Comment: breakdowns[0]=ref word for word